# DocuSign SOAP based API call error handling

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAP based API calls to create a DocuSign envelope.
I am able to create an envelope but in case there is a missing tag for the recipient or something else, I am unable to retrieve the correct error message from the API call.
Here is my code.

```
Dim client As New DocuSignServ.DSAPIServiceSoapClient
                Using scope As System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope = New System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)
                    SetHttpHeader()
                    Try
                        status = client.CreateAndSendEnvelope(newennvelope)
                        Session("status") = status
                        env.ID = status.EnvelopeID
                        envelopeid = env.ID
                    Catch ex2 As System.ServiceModel.FaultException
                        errormsg = "Error occured while creating an envelope into DocuSign account<br>Error Details : " & ex2.InnerException.Message.ToString
                    Catch ex As Exception

                        errormsg = "Error occured while creating an envelope into DocuSign account<br>Error Details : " & ex.Message.ToString
                    End Try
                End Using
```

Please advise,

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say "in case there is a missing tag".  I'm not understanding what problem or workflow you are trying to solve...

Comment: I meant that in case an error occurs while creating an envelope, how do I get the error details with a status code? Currently, whenever an error occurs while creating an envelope, I get a generic error message from DocuSign "Invalid username or password". I would like to get the details of the error message so that I can correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the WSDL for the DocuSign SOAP Service you'll see that there's an error element which specifies the `ErrorCode` and `Message`.

```
<s:complexType name="ErrorDetails">
<s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ErrorCode" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Message" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

You just have to parse that XML to retrieve the error code and description.

[DocuSign WSDL](https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsapi.wsdl)

Comment: I checked the WSDL before as well but could not find a way to refer to the error element from the API call that I am using to create an envelope. I am using "CreateandSendEnvelope" method to create an envelope which returns "DocuSignEnvelopeStatus" from which I am not able to refer to an error element.